# Выделение при нажатии tab

Tags: css3, html, css

Есть вот такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">

            *

            {
            list-style:none;
                text-decoration:none;
            }

            ul li
            {
                float:left;
                width:75px;
                height:40px;
                line-height:40px;
                background:#4169E1;
            }

            a
            {
                font-size:30px;
            }

            a:hover
            {
                background:black;
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>        
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">s #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="2">s #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="3">s #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="4">s #4</a></li>          
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии клавиши tab выделялась от остальных не только рамкой, но и становилась другого цвета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо применить псевдокласс `:focus` :

```
a:focus{
  background:black;
  color:red;
}
```